# In JMeter is it possible to create or run Maven & TestNG project?

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter is it possible to create or run Maven / TestNG java project? If possible then how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "run"? Both can be executed using [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler), check out [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article for more details.

In addition [TestNG can be executed programmatically](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically) using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) like

```
import org.testng.*

TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter()
TestNG testng = new TestNG()
testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { Run2.class })
testng.addListener(tla)
testng.run();
```